# How can a differential manifold also be a group?

Tags: differential-geometry, group-theory

I know that this is exactly what defines a [Lie Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group), but I don't understand the meaning of the proposition at all. I would really appreciate it if somebody could give me an *intuitive* explanation for the interplay between these concepts without bogging me down with ugly mathematical notation

For further context, I've computed Lie brackets in graduate courses and have some vague understanding of how the Lie derivative is a formal precursor to the notion of a covariant derivative in general relativity. Yet, for all the impetus that Lie groups have in gauge theories, I have not been able to delve into the topic further because I still don't understand the physical motivation for Lie groups.

Finally, it might be worth mentioning that Lie was part of Klein's Erlangen program and sought to formalize Riemann and Helmholtz's philosophy of geometry. If someone could shed light on that historical development, it would be amazing.